# PHP - Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert a rgb colors values to my database.
I have an array of strings as you can see here:

```php
array(4) {
    [0]=> string(15) "rgb(39, 32, 32)"
    [1]=> string(15) "rgb(96, 46, 46)"
    [2]=> string(16) "rgb(210, 70, 70)"
    [3]=> string(18) "rgb(246, 208, 208)"
}
```

But when I try to put it through the foreach cycle, it throws an array to string conversion exception. Can someone help me with this?

Here is the foreach cycle:

```php
foreach ($colors as $color) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO colors SET ID_Palette = :id_palette, Type = 'RGB', Code = :code";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result = $statement->execute([
        ":id_palette" => $ID_Palette,
        ":code" => $color
    ]);

    if (!$result) {
        var_dump($statement);
        $proceed = false;
    }
    else {
        $proceed = true;
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```php
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Paletky-new\action\create-palette.php on line 33

object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
    ["queryString"]=> string(69) "INSERT INTO colors SET ID_Palette = :id_palette, Type = 'RGB', Code = :code"
}
```

Comment: Which one is line 33? Since it's just a notice, it could be caused by some other issue.

Comment: What is your `$ID_Palette` value ? I guess `$ID_Palette` is an `array`. I can not just comment ... sorry

Comment: It shouldn't have been, but it was. Thank you!